# Effects of horizontal scaling on area under curve?

Tags: area, transformation

If f(x) is a continuous function and we stretch it horizontally by a factor n (multiply x by 1/n in the formula) then my intuition and some examples i solved tell me that if we look at a segment of the curve before stretching that covers the domain [a , b], that segment of the curve after stretching will cover the domain [n*a , n*b] and the area under that segment of the curve will be multiplied by n.
Is that assumption correct?
In short how does streching a curve horizontally by a factor n affect the area under the curve?

Comment: You are correct.  Are you familiar with the change of variables formula (i.e. "$u$-substitution")?

Comment: Xander Henderson  thank you for your answer, yes i used change of variable (u sub) alot but how does it relate to my question?

Comment: $u \mapsto \frac{x}{n}$.

Comment: Xander Henderson  thank you.